# How to get the single value from the database from the android?

Tags: android, database

I have a database for the employee details,i want to get the password from the database.am trying to get the value but am facing problem.How to retrieve the password from the databasssse....i have column keyid,fistname,lastname,mobile,dateofbirth,email,gender,personal id,date of joining,security question,answer,username,password.

**need to retrieve the password value**

```
    public List<String>  credientials(String eid) {

        List<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_EMPLOY, new String[] { 
                   KEY_PASSWORD,

        }, KEY_USERNAME + " = ?", new String[] { String.valueOf(eid) }, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null){
            do{
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            labels.add(cursor.getString(12));
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }cursor.close();
        db.close();
        return labels;
    }
```

My Error log Cat

```
09-13 13:24:00.354: E/AndroidRuntime(28252): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-13 13:24:00.354: E/AndroidRuntime(28252): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: [memory exhausted]
09-13 13:24:00.354: E/AndroidRuntime(28252):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-13 13:24:00.373: E/SQLiteDatabase(28252): close() was never explicitly called on database '/data/data/com.example.analyticbeans/databases/jk' 
09-13 13:24:00.373: E/SQLiteDatabase(28252): android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here
09-13 13:24:00.373: E/SQLiteDatabase(28252):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.<init>(SQLiteDatabase.java:1943)
09-13 13:24:00.373: E/SQLiteDatabase(28252):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:1007)
09-13 13:24:00.373: E/SQLiteDatabase(28252):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:986)
09-13 13:24:00.373: E/SQLiteDatabase(28252):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:1051)
09-13 13:24:00.373: E/SQLiteDatabase(28252):    at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:770)
09-13 13:24:00.373: E/SQLiteDatabase(28252):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:221)
09-13 13:24:00.373: E/SQLiteDatabase(28252):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:157)
09-13 13:24:00.373: E/SQLiteDatabase(28252):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:231)
09-13 13:24:00.373: E/SQLiteDatabase(28252):    at com.example.analyticbeans.dataBaseHelper.credientials(dataBaseHelper.java:129)
09-13 13:24:00.373: E/SQLiteDatabase(28252):    at com.example.analyticbeans.existinguserActivity.getData(existinguserActivity.java:86)
09-13 13:24:00.373: E/SQLiteDatabase(28252):    at com.example.analyticbeans.existinguserActivity.login(existinguserActivity.java:80)
09-13 13:24:00.373: E/SQLiteDatabase(28252):    at com.example.analyticbeans.existinguserActivity$1.onClick(existinguserActivity.java:55)
09-13 13:24:00.373: E/SQLiteDatabase(28252):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
09-13 13:24:00.373: E/SQLiteDatabase(28252):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
09-13 13:24:00.373: E/SQLiteDatabase(28252):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
09-13 13:24:00.373: E/SQLiteDatabase(28252):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-13 13:24:00.373: E/SQLiteDatabase(28252):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-13 13:24:00.373: E/SQLiteDatabase(28252):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
09-13 13:24:00.373: E/SQLiteDatabase(28252):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-13 13:24:00.373: E/SQLiteDatabase(28252):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-13 13:24:00.373: E/SQLiteDatabase(28252):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
09-13 13:24:00.373: E/SQLiteDatabase(28252):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
09-13 13:24:00.373: E/SQLiteDatabase(28252):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-13 13:24:00.484: E/System(28252): Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer
09-13 13:24:00.573: E/System(28252): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Don't have database lock!
09-13 13:24:00.573: E/System(28252):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.verifyLockOwner(SQLiteDatabase.java:2090)
09-13 13:24:00.573: E/System(28252):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase$1.entryRemoved(SQLiteDatabase.java:2182)
09-13 13:24:00.573: E/System(28252):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase$1.entryRemoved(SQLiteDatabase.java:2178)
09-13 13:24:00.573: E/System(28252):    at android.util.LruCache.trimToSize(LruCache.java:197)
09-13 13:24:00.573: E/System(28252):    at android.util.LruCache.evictAll(LruCache.java:285)
09-13 13:24:00.573: E/System(28252):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.deallocCachedSqlStatements(SQLiteDatabase.java:2143)
09-13 13:24:00.573: E/System(28252):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.closeClosable(SQLiteDatabase.java:1126)
09-13 13:24:00.573: E/System(28252):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.finalize(SQLiteDatabase.java:1914)
09-13 13:24:00.573: E/System(28252):    at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:182)
09-13 13:24:00.573: E/System(28252):    at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:168)
09-13 13:24:00.573: E/System(28252):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

**updated error**

```
09-13 14:08:19.173: E/AndroidRuntime(13156): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-13 14:08:19.173: E/AndroidRuntime(13156): android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 2
09-13 14:08:19.173: E/AndroidRuntime(13156):    at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:400)
09-13 14:08:19.173: E/AndroidRuntime(13156):    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
09-13 14:08:19.173: E/AndroidRuntime(13156):    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:50)
09-13 14:08:19.173: E/AndroidRuntime(13156):    at com.example.analyticbeans.dataBaseHelper.credientials(dataBaseHelper.java:136)
09-13 14:08:19.173: E/AndroidRuntime(13156):    at com.example.analyticbeans.existinguserActivity.getData(existinguserActivity.java:86)
09-13 14:08:19.173: E/AndroidRuntime(13156):    at com.example.analyticbeans.existinguserActivity.login(existinguserActivity.java:80)
09-13 14:08:19.173: E/AndroidRuntime(13156):    at com.example.analyticbeans.existinguserActivity$1.onClick(existinguserActivity.java:55)
09-13 14:08:19.173: E/AndroidRuntime(13156):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
09-13 14:08:19.173: E/AndroidRuntime(13156):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
09-13 14:08:19.173: E/AndroidRuntime(13156):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
09-13 14:08:19.173: E/AndroidRuntime(13156):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-13 14:08:19.173: E/AndroidRuntime(13156):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-13 14:08:19.173: E/AndroidRuntime(13156):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
09-13 14:08:19.173: E/AndroidRuntime(13156):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-13 14:08:19.173: E/AndroidRuntime(13156):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-13 14:08:19.173: E/AndroidRuntime(13156):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
09-13 14:08:19.173: E/AndroidRuntime(13156):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
09-13 14:08:19.173: E/AndroidRuntime(13156):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**update my full code**

```
package com.example.analyticbeans;


import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.List;

    import android.content.ContentValues;
    import android.content.Context;
 import android.database.Cursor;
  import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
     import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class dataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

// All Static variables
// Database Version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "jk";

// employee table name
private static final String TABLE_EMPLOY = "employeeTable";


// Contacts Table Columns names
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String KEY_FIRST_NAME ="firstName"; 
private static final String KEY_LAST_NAME ="lastName";
private static final String KEY_BIRTH ="birth";
private static final String KEY_MOBILENO="MobileNo";
private static final String KEY_GENDER="Gender";
private static final String KEY_PERSONALMAIL="PersonalMail";
private static final String KEY_ADDRESS="Address";
private static final String KEY_JOINING="Joining";
private static final String KEY_OFFICIALMAIL="OfficialMail";
private static final String KEY_QUESTION="Question";
private static final String KEY_ANSWER="Answer";
private static final String KEY_USERNAME="userName";
private static final String KEY_PASSWORD="password";

private String labels;




public dataBaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

   // Creating Tables
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_EMP_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_EMPLOY + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_FIRST_NAME + " TEXT ," 
            + KEY_LAST_NAME + " TEXT ," + KEY_BIRTH + " TEXT ,"+ KEY_MOBILENO + " NUMBER ,"
            + KEY_GENDER + " TEXT ,"+ KEY_PERSONALMAIL + " TEXT ,"
            + KEY_ADDRESS + " TEXT ,"+ KEY_JOINING + " TEXT ,"
            + KEY_OFFICIALMAIL + " TEXT ,"+ KEY_QUESTION + " TEXT ,"
            + KEY_ANSWER + " TEXT ,"
            + KEY_USERNAME + " TEXT ," + KEY_PASSWORD + " TEXT "+ ")";

    db.execSQL(CREATE_EMP_TABLE);
}
public void insertData(String firstname, String lastname,String birth,String mobile ,String spingender,
        String personalmail, String address,String joining,String official,String question,String answer,String username,
        String password) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_FIRST_NAME, firstname); 
    values.put(KEY_LAST_NAME, lastname);
    values.put(KEY_BIRTH, birth);
    values.put(KEY_MOBILENO,mobile);
    values.put(KEY_GENDER,spingender);
    values.put(KEY_PERSONALMAIL,personalmail);
    values.put(KEY_ADDRESS, address);
    values.put(KEY_JOINING, joining);
    values.put(KEY_OFFICIALMAIL,official);
    values.put(KEY_QUESTION, question);
    values.put(KEY_ANSWER, answer);
    values.put(KEY_USERNAME, username);
    values.put(KEY_PASSWORD, password);

    db.insert(TABLE_EMPLOY, null, values);
    db.close();

}
public List<String> getContact(String eid){
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
List<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_EMPLOY, new String[] { 
            KEY_ID,
            KEY_FIRST_NAME,
            KEY_LAST_NAME,KEY_BIRTH,KEY_MOBILENO,KEY_GENDER,KEY_PERSONALMAIL,KEY_JOINING,
            KEY_OFFICIALMAIL,KEY_QUESTION,KEY_ANSWER,KEY_PASSWORD
 }, KEY_USERNAME + " = ?", new String[] { String.valueOf(eid) }, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null){
        do{
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        labels.add(cursor.getString(0));
        labels.add(cursor.getString(1));
        labels.add(cursor.getString(2));
        labels.add(cursor.getString(3));
        labels.add(cursor.getString(4));
        labels.add(cursor.getString(5));
        labels.add(cursor.getString(6));
        labels.add(cursor.getString(7));
        labels.add(cursor.getString(8));
        labels.add(cursor.getString(9));
        labels.add(cursor.getString(10));
        labels.add(cursor.getString(11));
        labels.add(cursor.getString(13));


        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }cursor.close();
    db.close();

    // returning lables
    return labels;

}


    public List<String>  credientials(String eid) {

        List<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_EMPLOY, new String[] { 
                   KEY_PASSWORD,

        }, KEY_USERNAME + " = ?", new String[] { String.valueOf(eid) }, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor.getCount()>0){
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            do{

            labels.add(cursor.getString(13));
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        cursor.close();
        return labels;
    }
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {

}
```

}

Comment: Looks like you are not closing your database properly after the previous operation.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is not database but do-while loop that is not correctly implemented:

```
do {
   cursor.moveToFirst();
   labels.add(cursor.getString(12));
} while (cursor.moveToNext());
```

Change it to:

```
if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
   do {
      labels.add(cursor.getString(12)); // use rather getColumnIndex(<colname>)
   } while (cursor.moveToNext());
}
```

In your origin case you created infinite loop (first->next->first->next). This caused:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
```

Comment: 09-13 14:17:35.333: E/AndroidRuntime(17066): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 12 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.

Comment: your column 12 exist? I recommended you to use `getColumnIndex("columnname")` method instead yours.

Comment: labels.add(cursor.getColumnIndex("password"), eid); i try this but it return the username value only

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are creating an infinite loop here:

```
do{
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            labels.add(cursor.getString(12));
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
```

when you do `cursor.moveToFirst();` you put cursor to the first position and the latest instruction is `cursor.moveToNext()` that move forward the cursor

You just need to move `cursor.moveToFirst();` **before** the do instruction

Answer (score 0):

You just queried one column. your index is wrong. don't put `moveToFirst` in loop. keep in mind to catch exception.

```
public List<String>  credientials(String eid) {

            List<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_EMPLOY, new String[] { 
                       KEY_PASSWORD,

            }, KEY_USERNAME + " = ?", new String[] { String.valueOf(eid) }, null, null, null, null);

            try {
                if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()){
                    do{
                        labels.add(cursor.getString(0)); // KEY_PASSWORD
                    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
                }
            }
            finally {
                if (cursor != null) {
                    cursor.close();
                }

                if (db != null) {
                    db.close();
                }
            }


            return labels;
        }
```

Comment: 09-13 14:43:38.013: E/AndroidRuntime(26811): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index -1, size is 0
09-13 14:43:38.013: E/AndroidRuntime(26811):  at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
09-13 14:43:38.013: E/AndroidRuntime(26811):  at java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:143)
09-13 14:43:38.013: E/AndroidRuntime(26811):  at com.example.analyticbeans.dataBaseHelper.credientials(dataBaseHelper.java:139)